# Kubernetes Java API (KubernetesClient)

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

Simple question. I am using KubernetesClient by Fabric8. How do I get the deployment name by namespace? 
I tried

```
DeploymentList list = client.extensions().deployments().inNamespace(namespace).list();
```

I cannot get the name from it.. Any code snippet to get name by namespace will be great.

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
DeploymentList list = client.extensions().deployments().inNamespace(namespace).list();
for (Deployment d : list.getItems()) {
    System.out.println(d.getMetadata().getName());
}
```